# Cannot boot Windows 7 after updating to Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: dual-boot

I had a dual boot setup on my system, with Ubuntu 11.04 and Win7. Yesterday I updated Ubuntu to 11.10. Now , I cannot seem to be able to load Win7. I do see an entry for it on the boot menu, but when I select that entry and the screen goes black, with everything coming to a standstill. I tried waiting for it to respond but nothing happened.

I went through the forums and tried `grub-update` but when I do that, nothing really happens. I am not sure of this, but I get no output from grub for up to 10 minutes (can `grub-update` be made verbose?)

How can I fix this and get back to booting both OSs properly?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a [Windows recovery disk](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-system-repair-disc), you should be able to use this to regain access to Windows. However, when this process is done, it would have replaced GRUB's Master Boot Record with Windows', and if you want access to Ubuntu again you will have to run `update-grub` from a Live-CD or Live-USB, as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Answer (score 0):

your problem mybe due to the MBR when you installed the Ubuntu. I meet some problem when I install Acer Notebook. But I reinstall Ubuntu. and select use grub keep infomation on MBR. so you can see the Win7 item from boot menu.

I think you need reinstall Win7 . for I meet the "blue screen" after I install Ubuntu 10.04 and when I bootup win7. 
I use win7 backup disk image to recovery the win7. the recovery process spend me 2 hours time